# Launching an executable .jar on computer start so that when windows logs in the user does not see the Windows Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, jar

I am new to this side of the forum, so hopefully this is not off topic.

I wish to run an executable .jar file before the windows login screen is ever shown to the user so that when windows logs in to display the desktop, the user is first shown the full-screen view that my .jar displays without ever seeing the windows login screen/windows home screen.

To start off, (I have configured Windows to perform an automatic login on startup/restart to a non Admin User profile. I want to display my .jar UI instead of the Windows desktop for the Non Admin User only).

To Achieve Automatic Log In I Did the Following:

```
I did Run> "control userpasswords2" 
checked "Users must enter a user name and password to use the computer"
added Non Admin user as a standard user with no password (no Administrator privileges)
I made sure the Non Admin user was selected and unchecked "Users must enter     
a user name and password to use the computer" then hit Apply. This caused the     
"Automatically Log On" window to pop up and I made sure the Non Admin user with 
no password was the selected user.
```

My .jar is configured to be the top most window when it is open (and is non close-able unless an admin keyboard is used) and as such, when my .jar is open and running this effectively renders the desktop non clickable (which is what I want to accomplish). The user should never be able to click to windows desktop even on restart and should only have access to click on my .jar's User Interface.

How would you suggest to accomplish this?

I have tried:

```
Run gpedit.msc (Win+R -> gpedit.msc)
Go to "Computer Configuration" -> Windows Setting -> Scripts (Startup/shutdown)->
Go to Startup properties -> Show Files -> Placed my .bat and .jar inside
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup then closed that directory and 
in Startup Properties Add-> Script Name -> mybatFile.bat
```

The .bat file is located in the same directory `C:\NonAdmin` as my .jar and contains the following:

```
java -jar %~dp0myjarfile.jar %*
```

**Note: My .bat does successfully launch my .jar when it is double clicked**

but I havent been able to get my .jar to launch on startup so that the desktop is hidden behind it when logon occurs.

So I tried:

```
Log into Non Admin User > Put my .jar in C:\NonAdminProgram folder > Right Click > 
Create Shortcut > Press Windows + R keys > shell:startup > Explorer window showing > 
C:\Users\NonAdmin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup > 
Drag Shortcut of .jar to this directory
```

But this launches the .jar after the login screen is displayed so the user briefly sees the login screen before my .jar takes over and displays its UI on top. (NOT EXACTLY WHAT I WANT But close...

I want to make sure that the User never sees the Desktop on a restart or computer startup/boot - The first thing they see should be my .jar's UI instead - Every Time.

Thoughts?

Comment: Kiosk mode .....

Comment: I dont think that will solve my issue

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this